# Hiding <form> tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery

For some reason a `<form>` on my page won't hide/show using jQuery. I have other things in my form, like `<div>`s and `<table>`s, but I've isolated it down to these two input fields that are breaking it:
http://jsfiddle.net/3SDvm/2/

```
<form>
    <div>Random text</div>
<input id="multi" type="radio" name="style" value="checkbox"/>
    <label for="multi">Multiple options</label>

<input id="single" type="radio" name="style" value="radio" />
    <label for="single">Single option</label>
</form>​
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('form').slideUp(); 
});​
```

Is this normal behavior, or is there something I'm doing wrong? Tested on Chrome/IE/FF/Safari..

Comment: why don't you wrap the form in a `div` and hide the `div`. example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3SDvm/8/)

Comment: Strangely, it works when the inputs are removed: http://jsfiddle.net/3SDvm/10/

Comment: I've considered this workaround and hiding the actual elements of the form itself, but can't anyone explain why this happens?

At first I thought `<form>`s couldn't be animated, but once you take out those `<input>`s, everything works as expected.

Comment: Also, check this out - changing the `name`s makes it work: http://jsfiddle.net/3SDvm/11/ Weird. I wish someone would address this curiosity. Also check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/3SDvm/12/ Is this a bug? @actaeon: Maybe you should stress that you want an explanation and not a workaround if that's the case, I am very curious about this.

Comment: obviously jQuery doesn't like "style" as value of id or name. I can only guess it is somehow connected to indexing, as style is also a js property of the DOM nodes. Not sure if it is a valid value at all, although I never heard of this restriction.

Comment: @cypherabe: "style" is definitely a valid `name`, I tried a bunch of really messed up `name`s including js code as names and it worked - something specifically to do with the name "style" for some reason... And I tried an `<a name="style"></a>` and it was fine too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you use a name for a form field that matches a property or method of the parent form itself, this can happen. That includes style, but also id, action, submit, length, etc. jQuery attempts to work around this but there are still situations where it can occur. For more technical detail see here: http://kangax.github.com/domlint/

Answer (score 5):

Enclose the form content using a div and hide/show that div. I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/3SDvm/7/

With DerWaldschrat solution, each child will be hide/show individually, messing with the behavior that you want.

**Edit:** I updated the fiddle again with three ways to select the inner div and slide it up. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/3SDvm/9/

Comment: @WesleyMurch: It seems that form cannot be hidden and showed. I didn't know that too.

Comment: Yep. I tried to use style attr of form with display: none and it works too in OPs fiddle!

Comment: But when you try to do it with jQuery, we run into the same issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/3SDvm/14/

jQuery probably doesn't like me using `style` as a name.

Comment: @actaeon: Could be a jsfiddle issue (maybe?), did you run this anywhere else?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: The jsfiddle example is just a barebones of what I'm developing for a company. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: @WesleyMurch: here is some more tests: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/7P2AL/ When jQuery finds a form with a `input` with `name` not set as `style`, it works on the subsequent forms, even with `name="style"`. I post a issue in jQuery bug tracker: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12221

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hiding the form, which is an element with no real appearance, try to hide all children:

```
$("form *").hide();
```

Comment: I actually did this before, but I have elements that should only displayed on :hover, so doing `$('form *').show()` exposes them. I could add a `:not` in there, but this doesn't get at the problem that if I take out those `<input>`s, I can hide the form with the `<div>`.

Comment: Maybe you could wrap your complete form content in a fieldset, which is a (visible) region of your form

Comment: It's really not the same thing especially with the `slideUp` effect, better to hide a single element.

Comment: You and @davidbuzatto offer the same workaround, wrapping the form contents with a div or a fieldset, but it seems really hacky and I'm trying to keep my markup semantically meaningful..

Comment: With the <fieldset>, your markup is completely meaningfull, because this element ought to wrap groups of input elements.

Comment: @actaeon: this is not hacky at all: `div`, `span` etc are all display elements, while `form` is a rather strange element in HTML, it is only functional and has in itself no real display representation

Comment: @cypherabe: But `<form>`s can be stylized just as any other 'display' element, that's the point to CSS.

Plus I don't really need to group portions of the form, so adding a single fieldset/div isn't too attractive to me. Another container within a container just to fix a visual glitch?

Comment: yes, `form` can be styled, but it's semantically not really a display element. I think `schrat is on the right track with `fieldset`. Still, I can understand the wish to keep the structure lean. When not in overly-semantic-theory mood, I would just use the pure form, too.